# Quando Usar Factory AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Olá pessoal boa noite,

Eu queria saber duas coisas a primeira é quando eu devo usar a diretiva factory e a outra é se por exemplo dentro de uma factory eu posso fazer uma requisição Ajax e voltar o resultado dela em um método dessa minha factory, alguém teria um exemplo disto?

Answer (score 2):

Usar factory é uma das formas de se criar serviços com Angularjs. Além de factory, pode-se usar service e provider. As três variantes tem diferenças significativas(https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), porém todas criam um serviço singleton na sua applicação angularjs.

Sim, é possível e muito comum encapsular chamadas ajax dentro de um serviço, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    var getData = function () {
      return $http.get("api/getdata/");
   };
    return getData; // note que factory deve ter um retorno
});
```